# Чтение журнала отладки приложения с помощью C#

Tags: c#, отладка

Есть потребность прочитать журнал отладки другого приложения(**Debug.WriteLine();** например), есть ли какой нибудь класс для работы с другим приложением?

Comment: журнал - это что, текстовый файл? Вам файл надо прочитать?

Comment: `Debug.Log` работает только в отладочной сборке, в релизной сборке его физически нет. Следовательно и искать там нечего.

Comment: @aepot вот как раз нужно прочитать лог отладочной сборки

Comment: В C#/.NET нет `Debug.Log`. Откуда это метод? Из какой библиотеки? Что-то такое есть в Unity. Или вы имели в виду `Debugger.Log`? Или вы имели в виду `Debug.Write`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Debug.WriteLine();  он самый

Comment: М-м-м... Но ведь куда будет писать этот метод, зависит от подключенных TraceListener'ов. Они могут писать и в консоль, и в файл, и в эвентлог... | Другое приложение - ваше? Можете вносить в него изменения? Впрочем, если чужое, то оно должно быть в релизной сборке.